# Checking if template specialization of member function exists

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization, member-functions

Given

```
enum Type {A,B,C,D,E};

struct Thing {
   template <Type N> void foo() { }  // Do whatever.
};

template <> void Thing::foo<C>() { }  // Do whatever specialization.
template <> void Thing::foo<E>() { }  // Do whatever specialization.
```

How to determine during compile time that `Thing::foo` is specialized for `Type` values C and E but not for other values?

Comment: I'm not sure this is something that can be checked, at least generically.

Comment: I believe this answers your question.  [How to check if a template function was specialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072709/how-to-check-if-a-template-function-was-specialized)

Comment: can you modify `Thing` ?

Comment: Add `static_assert` to the primary template?